# Is the preimage of the generic point of the map $\mathbb{P}^n_R \to \operatorname{Spec}R$ open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, projective-schemes

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $z$ be the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}R$. 
Let $\pi: \mathbb{P}^n_R \to \operatorname{Spec}R$. I want to show that $\pi^{-1}(z)$ is open. Any comments and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think this is true?

Comment: This is certainly true when $R$ is a discrete valuation ring, because then the subset $\{z\} \subset \operatorname{Spec} R$ is open. In fact, if the map $\pi$ as above is closed, then $\{ z\} \subset R$ must be open, which puts strong restrictions on $R$.

Comment: @user45878 Does it also hold when $R$ is a valuation ring? not discrete valuation ring?